# IDEA Intellij: Underline files with compile time error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I have a couple of dependent java projects.

The problem is even though the build fails and the files contain obvious compile time errors, Intellij does not give any suggestions about the files that contain compilation errors.

In eclipse, it is too easy. You see the compilation errors right away.

I explored the `problems` tab, but honestly I don't find it helpful. It only tells that the project has some errors, that is it.

Seriously thinking about switching back to Eclipse if Intellij does not have such a basic feature.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502517/how-to-immediately-see-compile-errors-in-project-tree-of-intellij-idea

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775315/intellij-show-where-errors-are

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366569/104891

Comment: Or: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206208149-Show-all-compilation-errors-automatically-in-the-project-when-code-is-changed

Comment: Are you using Gradle?  I've had issues like this in the past and including the `idea` Gradle plugin and then running Gradle's `cleanIdea` and `idea` tasks fixed it.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html

Comment: Also try manually deleting the `build` and `out` directories, if they exist in your project, and then restart IntelliJ.  Sometimes IntelliJ's view in the editor does not match what it previously compiled into the `out` directory, especially if you ran Git commands (for example changing branches) from the terminal.